# Woocommerce's Cart page is being overwritten by my Page.php page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a little bit of a problem. My page.php seems to be overriding WooCommerce's cart page. The page is already created (generated by WooCommerce with the shortcode intact) named Cart.

I know that my page.php is overriding it, but I don't know how to stop that. Here is the code for my page.php page:

```
<?php 
get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) {

    //Work with us page
    $workwithuspage = "work with us";
    $pitch = "pitch an idea";
    $cart = "cart";

    if($workwithuspage == strtolower(get_the_title()))
    {
        //Page stuff here!
        $image = wpse_get_images();
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="hero">
            <div class="container heroImage" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image->guid;?>');">
                <div class="col-md-7"></div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="pageText">
                        Work with Us
                    </div>
                    <div class="subText">
                        <?php echo $image->post_content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyBg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="box-style">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            Got a comic idea and want it published?
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-text">
                            Tell us your desires, so we can slap it on a comic book and sell it for millions. Ya dig?
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-button-container">
                            <?php
                                $pitch = get_page_by_title('pitch an idea');
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($pitch); ?>"><div class="button large">Pitch an Idea</div></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="box-style">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            Want to work on one of our great titles?
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-text">
                            Tell us your desires, so we can slap it on a comic book and sell it for millions. Ya dig?
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-button-container">
                            <div class="button large">Find Jobs</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ourstandards">
            <div class="coloroverlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="pageHeaderText">
                            Our Standards
                        </div>
                        <div class="bodyTxt">
                            <p>
                                At On Target Network, we strive to promote consistency, 
                                communication and passion in all areas of work and we expect the same of our artists. 
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                We understand the nature of creators and seek to raise ourselves to higher and higher standards. To do that, we vet and 
                                review series pitches with a carefully selected panel of writers and artists.
                            </p>
                            <br /><br />
                            <p>
                                Got questions? We'll be happy to help.
                            </p>
                            <div id="sendUsQ" class="secondaryBtn">
                                Send us your questions
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <?php
    }
    else if($pitch == strtolower(get_the_title()))
    {
        ?>
        </div>
        <div  id="pitchImg" class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-7"></div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="pageText">
                        Pitch an Idea
                    </div>
                    <div class="subText">
                        <?php echo $image->post_content; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyBg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="pageHeaderText dark">
                        Start your pitch here
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <?php
                        if ( isset($si_contact_form) )  {
                            echo $si_contact_form->si_contact_form_short_code( array( 'form' => '1' ) );
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
get_footer();
?>
```

I have conditional ifs for pages I wanted to customize, but I fear in doing that, it has overridden (somehow) the cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce adds the cart using shortcodes; shortcodes get displayed as part of the page content. WP uses the `the_content()` function to display the content for a particular page or post. You've removed `the_content()` from your page template, therefore the cart doesn't display.

Looking at your page template, you've removed `the_content()` and inlined all your content directly into the template rather than fetching it from the database. This is atypical of a WP site in general, but I understand that sometimes a site starts off static and you just want to get it 'into' WP.

You're also using a bunch conditionals to display different chunks of content, which runs against the idea of using templates. My suggestion would be to create separate page templates for your 'pitch' and 'work with us' pages, and make `page.php` just a default page template that has `the_content()`. This way you have a generic template you can use for any page, including the cart page.

Check [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) for more info on creating custom page templates, but in a nutshell, you add a comment to the top of the file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

Then save your file in your theme folder. Common practice is to name it along the line of `page-pitch.php` so you can easily identify it. Then in the admin area you can assign the template to any page you want simply by selecting it from the drop down menu.

Splitting your different content into separate templates has a couple of benefits; namely you no longer have to use conditionals for checking the page titles (which can vary from install to install) and makes it much easier for you to debug things.

Comment: You know, I attempted to do an "else" statement to see if the cart page would work with `the_content()`, however, it didn't.

Comment: And what I mean by it didn't, is that it was an empty page.

Comment: Also, is there a best practice with creating different page templates?

Comment: Updated answer above. Make `page.php` a default page template by removing all your conditionals and restore `the_content()` and see if it works then.

Comment: The page templates work perfectly, however, the cart page has yet to work.

Comment: All I have now on the page.php page is this:

`<?php 
    get_header();
    
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        
        the_content();
        
    }

    get_footer();
?>`

Comment: Log into your admin area and edit your cart page. Try adding some filler text to the page and save it and check the results. You need to establish if the problem is specifically with the cart or with all content.

Comment: Ah hah. Nothing is showing up after putting in filler text.

Comment: I see, you're missing `the_post()`, which should go before `the_content()`. See [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) for examples of how the default WP loop is set up

Comment: Thank you. It gets annoying staring at the code for a long time you start missing the basics. To everyone out there, I was missing `The Loop`